# Error while counting hashtags using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, twitter, pyspark

I am working on a twitter dataset. I have the data in JSON format. The structure is:

```
root
|-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- place: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bounding_box: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- place_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
```

The code I am using for counting hashtag is this:

```
non_retweets = tweets.where("retweeted_status IS NULL")
hashtag = non_retweets.select('text').flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ").filter(lambda x: x.startWith("#"))

hashtag = hashtag.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

hashtag.collect()
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
 File "<ipython-input-112-11fd8cbc056d>",line 4
hashtag = hashtag.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
      ^
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

I am not able to point out what my error is. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `)` after filter. That why it is showing `Invalid syntax`.

Please check below code.

```
hashtag = non_retweets.select('text').flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")).filter(lambda x: x.startWith("#"))
```

Comment: Oh thanks, btw your you added the bracket in the wrong place. It is before the filter. But thank you so much.